# How to get token expiration date from ADO using token API?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to get the token expiration date or permission revoke for specific ado token, how can we do that?
I am referring the [API](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/Orgname/_apis/Token/SessionTokens?displayFilterOption=1&createdByOption=3&sortByOption=3&isSortAscending=true&startRowNumber=1&pageSize=100&api-version=5.0-preview.1) and it gives me the list of PAT with date. But don't which one should I use for checking repository expiration date.

I am also referring the MS ADO [API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).
But when call the API mention in document then gettting unauthorized error,
I am passing my PAT and using Basic Auth. why getting unauthorized error, while above mention api work?

How can I identify the repository access expiration date using above API and how to use API mention in document?

Comment: If you are getting an "unauthorized" error when making this API call, it may be because the PAT you are using does not have the necessary permissions to list PATs. The `List Personal Access Tokens` API requires the `Token Administration` permission. you can either generate a new PAT with the necessary permission or add it to your existing PAT.

Comment: I have Token Administration permission, Also want to check whether I can access repository or not because there are list, how can I identify repo expiration date from list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no direct API available using but below post is helpful to resolve the issue
[Get expiration date using PAT](https://vinijmoura.medium.com/how-to-personal-access-tokens-expiration-mapping-5630e5db1f99)

Comment: Add context alongside your link for an improved answer. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Provide%20context%20for%20links